# RuntimeError: abort(ReferenceError: proccess is not defined)

Tags: ropsten, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am following this instructions https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html

When I run the following command (last step of the instructions)

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten --verbose
```

I receive this:

```
  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/hardhat.config.js +0ms
  hardhat:core:global-dir Looking up Client Id at /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/hardhat-nodejs/analytics.json +0ms
  hardhat:core:global-dir Client Id found: 286bbcd2-e092-4d91-9301-8a0bc02921f1 +11ms
  hardhat:core:hre Creating HardhatRuntimeEnvironment +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task run +51ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile +1ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:get-compilation-tasks +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:get-source-paths +1ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:get-source-names +5ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:get-dependency-graph +7ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:read-file +2ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:get-compilation-jobs +5ms
  hardhat:core:tasks:compile The dependency graph was divided in '1' connected components +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:get-compilation-job-for-file +1ms
  hardhat:core:compilation-job File '/Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/contracts/Transaction.sol' will be compiled with version '0.8.0' +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:handle-compilation-jobs-failures +2ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:filter-compilation-jobs +0ms
  hardhat:core:tasks:compile '1' jobs were filtered out +5ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:merge-compilation-jobs +2ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:compile-jobs +1ms
  hardhat:core:tasks:compile No compilation jobs to compile +1ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:log:nothing-to-compile +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:solidity:log:compilation-result +4ms
  hardhat:core:hre Running task compile:remove-obsolete-artifacts +0ms
  hardhat:core:tasks:run Running script scripts/deploy.js in a subprocess so we can wait for it to complete +0ms
  hardhat:core:scripts-runner Creating Hardhat subprocess to run scripts/deploy.js +0ms
  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/hardhat.config.js +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Creating HardhatRuntimeEnvironment +0ms
  hardhat:core:hre Creating provider for network ropsten +175ms
Transactions deployed to:  0x64afCB54c2493Fb9Ec97aeaC0f340b7abc27730b
ReferenceError: proccess is not defined
    at runMain (/Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/scripts/deploy.js:13:5)
ReferenceError: proccess is not defined
ReferenceError: proccess is not defined

   ... lots of binary ...

    RuntimeError: abort(ReferenceError: proccess is not defined). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
        at process.abort (/Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:13938)
        at process.emit (node:events:390:28)
        at process.emit (/Users/myuser/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/BlockchainProjects/krypt/smart_contract/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:516:21)
        at emit (node:internal/process/promises:136:22)
        at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:242:25)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)
```

however, when I check my ropsten-eth balance on metamask I can see that I spent some ropsten-eth for deploying.

I have also a json file of the smart contract with `abi` section in my folder `artifacts/contracts/contract`.

But because of my error I cannot see the address where the smart contract was deployed to and I don't know what led to the error.

my `deploy.js` file

```
const main = async () => {
  const Transactions = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Transactions");
  const transactions = await Transactions.deploy();

  await transactions.deployed();

  console.log('Transactions deployed to: ', transactions.address);
}

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    proccess.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    proccess.exit(1);
  }
}

runMain();
```

my hardhat.config.js file

```
const { solidity } = require('ethereum-waffle')

require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle')

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.0',
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: 'https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/*****************',
      accounts: [ '******************************' ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see how this relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `process` is misspelt as `proccess`. It should be

```js
try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: oh stupid. thanks very much for pointing out! When new to a topic, one thinks always there must be something I don't know instead of checking what is known